# Audio recorder eclipse Android clipping -some parts was cut

Tags: android, eclipse, audio-recording, clipping

Every person reads 10 sentences. I take some people's voices, and then I listen to the voice. When I listen the voice, only one part gives clipping.

Let's say one person says "Studying is very important" – I hear that "Studying is very portant".

Some part was cut. What is the reason for this?

```
public static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
public static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
public static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "Kayitlar";
public static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
public static final int sampleRate = 16000;
public static final int channels = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
public static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

public AudioRecord recorder = null;
private AudioTrack maPlayer = null;
public int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,channels,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
public Thread recordingThread = null;
public boolean isRecording = false;
public Button start, stop;
public int counter = 1;
public String kisiDosyaAd;

public void startRecording(){
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                                    sampleRate, channels,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,bufferSize);

    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //counter = 1;
                    writeAudioDataToFile();
            }
```

Comment: Did you try to use different samplerates?

Comment: I used also 44000 sample rate. In that time I hear nothing. Do you have other suggestions?please.